# How to edit background color of only one sidebar?

Tags: php, css, child-theme

I'm using Oulipo theme on [this site](http://www.pranesh.inteftrust.org/), which has two sidebars.

> **I'd like to ask how can I change the background color of only the left
>   sidebar?**

Also, how to change the text, hyperlink, hover and background colors for

1. Front menu located in left sidebar.
2. Search field located at upper right corner.

Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

just add a background-color:#000000; to the #main_nav div in your css. change 000000 (black) to whatever hex color you want. Help w/ that here: http://www.december.com/html/spec/color.html

Comment: I already tried doing that; but it becomes like this -  (http://pranesh.inteftrust.org). I'd like to change the color of entire sidebar, while it just changes a small portion of that.

Comment: site isn't loading for me anymore. "ntechi" left a comment about a plugin called firebug for firefox or chrome... use that... it'll help display what div and class name to focus on to edit in your css file.

Answer (score 0):

For your all questions, I guess only one plugin will be perfect for you,
Use firefox, and install [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/downloads/) then with the help of its selection function, try to catch the areas like sidebar, widgets, posts-content etc by hovering mouse cursor and click on them, then just edit the CSS part or HTML part according to your choice. And when finally you are done with the CSS or HTML copy paste that into your themes respective css or php  file

This is the best practice for editing the CSS and HTML of a website